# Good practices regarding primary indexes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I have a MongoDB database with 2 main collections. The database stores both the raw data that arrives from time to time and processed data that is used by a web application.

- `RAW`: here I store raw data which should never be modified. Only when new raw data arrives it can have new documents inserted. And for the sake of the example we may assume that each document in this collection corresponds to a product.
- `PRODUCTS`: here I store documents that also correspond to products (the same set of products I store in `RAW`, but here the products have some additional fields). The general idea is that once new raw data arrives, the new documents are also inserted to this collection, but first I compute some additional metrics and add additional fields to the new documents. This collection also talks to a web application through which users may not only explore the data but also modify some of the fields (this is one of the reasons I want to have `RAW` completely separated from the web application).

So here is the question: should I have separate `ObjectId` primary indexes in the two collections (so there is no relationship between their `_id` fields) or is it good to use the same `_id` in both collections.

It seems to me that second approach may be better as it saves me establishing one index (otherwise in the `PRODUCTS` collection I would have to maintain indexes on both `_id` and some other field through which I would be able to map documents from `PRODUCTS` to `RAW`).

However, I also believe that there may be a problem with this strategy that I do not see.

So, I will be grateful for any hints on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the `PRODUCTS` collection would contain entries derived from the `RAW` collection. In this case, I don't see any issue in reusing the `_id` field of the `RAW` collection in the `PRODUCT` collection.

Having said that, it's best to test this design with your application and your intended usage pattern. From MongoDB side of things, `_id` is required to be unique only across a single collection, so the duplicated `_id` entry across two different collections do not pose a problem. If there's any confusion regarding the `_id` values, it will likely happen in the application layer rather than the database layer.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I will stick to reusing the same `_id` in both collections as I need to maintain mapping between them, so I can easily tell which product from `RAW` is not yet moved to `PRODUCTS`.